# Android Java Socket output keeps growing

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm writing an Application that connects with a Telnet server using sockets in Android (Java). Every 2 seconds it sends a command to the server, to which the server replies. When i receive the output from the server the reader seems to keep adding it up to data received in the past. Clearly a BufferedReader doesn't have a 'flush' option, and the topics i found online so far don't seem to apply in this situation. Anyone willing to help me out with this? I'm stuck on it for a week now.

```
runthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            String remoteip = "192.168.1.39";

            int remoteport = 4212;



            Socket telnet = null;
            try {
                telnet = new Socket(remoteip, remoteport);
            }catch(UnknownHostException e){
                System.out.println("Exception telnet: " + e.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Exception IO: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                telnet.setKeepAlive(true);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception keepalive: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            final BufferedReader reader;
            final PrintWriter writer;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(telnet.getInputStream()));
                writer = new PrintWriter(telnet.getOutputStream());
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception reader/writer: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            char[] buffer = new char[4096]; // Read 4K characters at a time
            int len; // How many chars read each time
            try {
                while ((len = reader.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
                    String readchar = new String(buffer, 0, len);
                    System.out.println(readchar); //THIS IS WHERE IT PRINTS THE OUTPUT


                    stateTimer = new Timer();
                    stateTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            writer.print("status\n"); //ASK FOR SOME OUTPUT EVERY 2 SECONDS
                            writer.flush();
                        }

                    }, 0, 2000);

                    }
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("while() exception:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    runthread.start();
```

Comment: Why do you spawn a new timer for every read? This seems wrong, try moving that part outside the while loop.

Comment: Ah, my bad... I should've moved it before while() instead of after. Thanks!

Comment: Did it fix your issue?